# How to capture network traffic data of specific third-party App? Is it possibile?

Tags: android, network-traffic

Now I have a demand to capture the network traffic data of some specific third-party Apps, get the content and type of the data for future use, does Android provide API for this? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: data communication means? listen to webservices?

Comment: Yes, network communication data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like tcpdump. It is not possible with in android app from another app or service. Unless you have root previliges, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: For example, I want to get the content and type of the data that WhatsApp send to/receive from its server(**for good use**), and get the IP address of the server(since I will still send the data to the same address, it's kind of like middle attack).

Comment: I understand what you intend to do. But as far as i know each app is an independent process in android and is sandboxed with in itself so it wont be possible for other apps to do spoof the data and respond to like the MITM

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, If you need to make it in a-synchronize mode, you can use AsyncHttpClient else you can use HttpClient. Read about them.

Comment: no, put you can use make server task to make that and expose it as web service then you can use AsyncHttpClient to get the get the result from this web service.